# How to configure a package to export subdirectory in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently, I have a common package where the components are exported as Named export like so in the `src/index.js`

```
export ComponentA from './ComponentA'
export ComponentB from './ComponentB'
```

In a different project where this is a dependent package I am importing it as

```
import { ComponentA, ComponentB } from 'my-package';
```

instead, I need to import it like

```
import ComponentA from 'my-package/ComponentA'
```

This is so that I can use react.lazy() and use it as

```
const LazyComponentA = React.lazy(()=> import('my-package/ComponentA'))
```

This is under the assumption that if I lazyload the component like this it would only download `ComponentA` and not the others from 'my-package' Package.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In `my-package/ComponentA` add `index.js` file with your imports:

```
// my-package/ComponentA/index.js
import { ComponentA } from "./some-path";
export default ComponentA;
```